# Matlab: find last non-NaN element and replace it with NaN

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, nan

How can I find for each row of the matrix in Matlab the index of the last non-NaN element and replace these values with NaN?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: if `x` is your matrix, then you can get the index with `[~,ind]=max(isnan(x),[],2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method may be an implementation. It uses a `Logical_Array` that indicates `NaN` values using "1" and `non-NaN` values using "0". Then each row using `find()` returns all the indices that are "0"/`non-NaN` number. By evaluating the maximum index using `max()` the last/greatest column can be retrieved for each respective row. Taking the max allows scenarios where the `NaN` values are scattered to be accommodated.

```
Matrix = [1 2 NaN 4 5;
         1 NaN 3 NaN 5;
         1 2 NaN NaN NaN];
     
[Matrix_Height,~] = size(Matrix);

Logical_Array = isnan(Matrix);

for Row = 1: +1: Matrix_Height
    
    Target_Row = Logical_Array(Row,:);
    [Minimum,Indices] = find(Target_Row == 0);
    Last_Non_NaN_Index = max(Indices);
    Matrix(Row,Last_Non_NaN_Index) = NaN;
    
end

Matrix
```

### Result of Test Matrix:

Row 1: 5 → NaN 
Row 2: 5 → NaN 
Row 3: 2 → NaN

[image: Results Image]

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Answer (score 1):

Consider `x` as:

```
x = [1   2   3   nan;
     3   4   nan nan;
     1   nan nan nan;
     nan nan nan nan]
```

You can obtain the index, for each row, of the first `nan` value with:

```
[~,ind]=max(isnan(x),[],2);
```

And then using `sub2ind` :

```
x(sub2ind(size(x),max(ind.'-1,1),1:length(x))) = nan
```

Or the one-liner:

```
x((circshift(isnan(x),-1)+isnan(x))>0)=nan
```